# Issue in passing multiple way points to Google map API

Tags: android, google-maps

I am trying to pass multiple way points between an origin and destination, so that when I get the response I can draw the route on Google map.

This is a sample call I make (in my original API call, there are more way points):

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=41.3758887,2.1745799999999917&waypoints=41.39097711845494,2.1807326361331434&41.38680260504134,2.188132850805232&41.38458293055814,2.1758925899657697&destination=41.38394800519846,2.166872321048686&sensor=true&mode=walking

Is the above format right for passing multiple way points?

The main issue I am facing is that the route is not going through all the way points I am passing.

I am always getting a "waypoint_order" : [ 0 ].

Answer (score 2):

use '%7C' instead of '&' in your waypoint request. i.e.

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=41.3758887,2.1745799999999917&waypoints=41.39097711845494,2.1807326361331434%7C41.38680260504134,2.188132850805232%7C41.38458293055814,2.1758925899657697&destination=41.38394800519846,2.166872321048686&sensor=true&mode=walking

Comment: Yes they are the same :)